# React undefined error after build is deployed

Tags: reactjs

My react app which runs fine after `npm start` has an issue after it is built. The build will run and display the app and suddenly fail with the following error.

```
TypeError: can't access property "length", t is undefined
```

The thing is why would it work fine before it is built and fail in the build with an error such as a TypeError? Am I missing something here? The problem seems to occur when setting the state with new values, none of which is undefined. And even if the values were off it should still be reflected in the testing part using `npm start` as it is using the same APIs and both running on the same server.
I suspect that a component that is rendered when the state is set fails in the build. Please help to resolve if similar behaviour has been observed.

Comment: Could you post more info about the error, maybe stacktrace. It appears you are expecting length to exist when it doesn’t.

Comment: @NathanHall Yes it seems. But my questions is why would it only fail in the build? I will try to post more information if possible.